# Make this jQuery code a little more dynamic

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    if (window.location.href.indexOf("seniors") > -1) {
        var $ul_senior = $('<ul class="sub-menu-jquery"></ul>');
        $("#menu-item-630").append($ul_senior);
        $("#menu-carecenter-seniors-menu li").each(function () {
            var $li = $(this);
            $($li).clone().appendTo(".sub-menu-jquery");
        });
    };
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("medical") > -1) {
        var $ul_medical = $('<ul class="sub-menu-jquery"></ul>');
        $("#menu-item-636").append($ul_medical);
        $("#menu-carecenter-medical-menu li").each(function () {
            var $li = $(this);
            $($li).clone().appendTo(".sub-menu-jquery");
        });
    };
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("foundation") > -1) {
        var $ul_foundation = $('<ul class="sub-menu-jquery"></ul>');
        $("#menu-item-635").append($ul_foundation);
        $("#menu-carecenter-foundation-menu li").each(function () {
            var $li = $(this);
            $($li).clone().appendTo(".sub-menu-jquery");
        });
    };
});
```

What this code does is it clones the links from a sidebar from a Wordpress site and it adds them to the main-nav depending on which section of the site you're in.

The more I look into this code, the more I realize I could make it more dynamic by extracting the 'seniors' or 'medical' or 'foundation' #id from the sidebar, and adding it to the main-nav based on the title of the  tag (also either 'seniors' or 'medical' or 'foundation'.

This way, I wouldn't need to use the specific #menu-item-xxx and it would be totally dynamic.

Pretty sure the html() function would need to be used. But not sure how.

Comment: HTML would be nice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably just extract out the common areas of the Javascript into a function. Maybe something like this?

```
addMenuItem("seniors", "630");
addMenuItem("medical", "636");
addMenuItem("foundation", "635");

function addMenuItem(location, item) {
if (window.location.href.indexOf(location) > -1) {
    var $ul = $('<ul class="sub-menu-jquery"></ul>');
    $("#menu-item-" + item).append($ul);
    $("#menu-carecenter-" + location + "-menu li").each(function() {
        var $li = $(this);
        $($li).clone().appendTo(".sub-menu-jquery");
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using arrays you can make it better.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    arrayHref = ['seniors', 'medical', 'foundation'];
    arrayID = ['menu-item-630', 'menu-item-636', 'menu-item-635'];
    $.each(arrayHref, function (index, value)) {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf(value)) {
            var $ul = $('<ul class="sub-menu-jquery"></ul>');
            $('#' + arrayID[index]).append($ul);
            $("#menu-carecenter-" + value + "-menu li").each(function () {
                var $li = $(this);
                $($li).clone().appendTo(".sub-menu-jquery");
            });
        }
    });
});
```